# Autocompletion using UITextView should change text in range

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring

I followed Ray Wenderlich's tutorial on text autocompletion here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/336/how-to-auto-complete-with-custom-values

And it works great, but it only allows searching for a string that is contained in the textView. I need it to search for multiple strings in the same view. For example:

```
Hi @user, how's @steve
```

Should search for both occurrences of the @. Here is the original code:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range 
replacementString:(NSString *)string {
 autocompleteTableView.hidden = NO;

    NSString *substring = [NSString stringWithString:textField.text];
    substring = [substring stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    [self searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring:substring];
    return YES;
}
```

And here is mine:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range 
replacementString:(NSString *)string {

NSArray* items = [textView.text componentsSeparatedByString:@"@"];

if([items count] > 0 && [[items lastObject] length]){
    NSString *substring = [NSString stringWithString:[items lastObject]];
    [self searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring:substring];

    }
return YES;
}
```

And everything works, but it seems to be a character behind. So typing "J" would result in nothing, but "Jo" would return results for "J". I'm thinking it has to do with:

```
 [substring stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string]
```

But anything I try crashes with an NSRange out of bounds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, are we talking about a text field or a text view?  They are different!  Your code refers to both.  I will just go with `textField` since that's in the name of the method.

At the time you receive `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:`, `textField.text` has not been changed to contain the replacement string.  So when the user types “J”, `textField.text` doesn't contain the `J` yet.

Ray's method handles this by performing the substitution.  When you try to do the substitution, it fails because your `substring` variable doesn't contain a copy of `textField.text`.  Your `substring` only contains a part of `textField.text`.  That's why you get an out-of-bounds exception - your range is out of bounds because `substring` is shorter than `textField.text`.

So perhaps you should perform the replacement before you split the string. Try this:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSString *changedText = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    NSArray* items = [changedText componentsSeparatedByString:@"@"];

    if([items count] > 0 && [[items lastObject] length]){
        NSString *substring = [NSString stringWithString:[items lastObject]];
        [self searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring:substring];

    }
    return YES;

}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Didn't even think about doing the replacement before hand. Also fixed my array size. Thanks!