# Get currently typed word in a UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, substring, nsrange

I want to get the currently typed word in a `UITextView`. A way to get a completely typed word can be found here [UITEXTVIEW: Get the recent word typed in uitextview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14085034/uitextview-get-the-recent-word-typed-in-uitextview), however, I want to get the word while it is being typed (no matter where it is typed, beginning, middle, end of `UITextView`).

I guess what defines a word being typed is a whitespace character followed by alphanumeric characters, or if the current location (somehow to figure out with `range.location`) is the beginning of the `UITextView` then whatever follows up should be considered as word as well. A word is finished being typed when another whitespace character follows.

I tried with:

```
 - (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text`
```

but I have a problem finding the correct range.

In short again: I need to find the substring in a `UITextView`, where substring is the currently typed word.

**EDIT**: Because the question came up. I'm using `NSLayoutManager` and bind a `NSTextContainer` to it, which then is passed as layoutManager to a `NSTextStorage`.

**EDIT2**: The main problem with `(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text` is that the `range.location` is not the same as the indicator is, but always 1 less. If the cursor is at position 1, after typing one letter, `range.location` would return 0. Any way around this? In addition the `text` attribute of `UITextView` seems to be off by 1 as well. When the text is `foobar` and I output the `UITextView.text` then I get `fooba` instead. Therefore `range.location+1` returns the exception `Range {0, 1} out of bounds; string length 0'`

**EDIT3**:
Maybe it is easier to get my wanted result with the `NSTextStorage` instead of `UITextView`?

Comment: `- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text` method will give you range for single character at a time and you have to take it one by one and make latest word

Comment: Where are you wanting to display it? In a label or? That will help me

Comment: You should look into `UITextInputProtocol`. If you face any issues implementing code, let me know.

Comment: @The-Rooster It's a little 'complicated' setup. I'm using `NSLayoutManager`and bind a `NSTextContainer` to it, which then is passed as `layoutManager` to a `NSTextStorage`.

Comment: @n00bProgrammer I just took a look at `UITextInputProtocol` and don't really know how it is suppose to help. Any specifics in the `UITextInputProtocol` where I should take a closer look at?

Comment: Checkout my solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/46828561/2020034

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UITextView delegate method : `-textView:textView shouldChangeTextInRange:range replacementText:text` what actaully does is that it asks whether the specified text should be replaced in the text view in the specified range of `textView.text` .

This method will be invoked each time when we type a charactor before updating that to the text view. That is why you are getting the `range.location` as 0, when you type the very first character in the `textView`.

Only if the return of this method is true, the `textView` is getting updated with what we have typed in the `textView`.

This is the definition of the parameters of the `-textView:textView shouldChangeTextInRange:range replacementText:text` method as provided by apple:

**range** :- The current selection range. If the length of the range is 0, range reflects the current insertion point. If the user presses the Delete key, the length of the range is 1 and an empty string object replaces that single character.
**text** :- The text to insert.

So this is what the explanation for the method and your requirement can meet like as follows:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
        //Un-commend this check below :If you want to detect the word only while new line or white space charactor input 
        //if ([text isEqualToString:@" "] || [text isEqualToString:@"\n"])
        //{
            // Getting the textView text upto the current editing location
            NSString * stringToRange = [textView.text substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0,range.location)];

            // Appending the currently typed charactor
            stringToRange = [stringToRange stringByAppendingString:text];

            // Processing the last typed word 
            NSArray *wordArray       = [stringToRange componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
            NSString * wordTyped     = [wordArray lastObject];

            // wordTyped will give you the last typed object
            NSLog(@"\nWordTyped :  %@",wordTyped);
        //}
        return YES;
}
```

Comment: I've seen this solution before, but unfortunately it doesn't quite work. When you output `wordTyped`, the word you get is always one character short. So, lets say you just typed `foobar`, `NSLog` will output you `fooba` for the `wordTyped`.

Comment: That's what I thought at the beginning too, but that doesn't work at all and also crashes the app when the `UITextView` was empty before and gives an out of bounds exception

Comment: That doesn't work, because it will only output the `wordTyped`, if a whitespace character or linebreak is received, but I want to get the output all the time.

Comment: The problem is described in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9155381/autocompletion-using-uitextview-should-change-text-in-range. The idea is to have the replacement before.

Answer (score 10):

The following is an example of a skeletal structure that uses `UITextInput` and `UITextInputTokenizer` to give the word that is being currently typed/edited.

```
- (void) textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {

    NSRange selectedRange = textView.selectedRange;

    UITextPosition *beginning = textView.beginningOfDocument;
    UITextPosition *start = [textView positionFromPosition:beginning offset:selectedRange.location];
    UITextPosition *end = [textView positionFromPosition:start offset:selectedRange.length];

    UITextRange* textRange = [textView.tokenizer rangeEnclosingPosition:end withGranularity:UITextGranularityWord inDirection:UITextLayoutDirectionLeft];

    NSLog(@"Word that is currently being edited is : %@", [textView textInRange:textRange]);
}
```

This will give you the entire **word** that is currently being typed.

For instance if you are typing ***input*** and have typed ***inp*** it will give you ***inp***. Further if you are in the middle of the word ***middle*** and change it to ***midddle***, it will give you ***midddle***. The trick here is **tokenizing**.

I have placed the code inside `textViewDidChange:` so that you get the word *after* it's been typed/edited. If you want it *before* the last character change (i.e. the word that is about to be changed), place the code in `textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:`.

**PS:** You will have to handle edge cases like sentences and paragraphs being pasted/removed. You can modify this code to get characters/sentences/paragraphs etc, instead of just words by changing the granularity. Look into the declaration of `UITextGranularity` `ENUM` for more options:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UITextGranularity) {
    UITextGranularityCharacter,
    UITextGranularityWord,
    UITextGranularitySentence,
    UITextGranularityParagraph,
    UITextGranularityLine,
    UITextGranularityDocument
};
```

Comment: Great, but it does not work with a _UITextGranularityWord_ and special characters : ex: "blabla **#myCurrentlyEditedWord** blabla", that's return "myCurrentlyEditedWord" without the **"#"**.

Comment: @Ded77 you're absolutely right. That's because granularity works with languages (I think, but I'm not sure). **#**, here is a special character. As mentioned in the **PS** part of the answer, you will have to handle edge cases, and this is an edge case. One thing you can do is keep a reference to the range of the last word detected and compare its **location+range** with the **location** of the current word detected. If they're the same, that means it's one word (hashtag, handle, etc). Easier way would be to extract the detected word from the main string and check if it is preceded by **#/@**.

Comment: This is good, but it doesn't work for symbols  too bad, because this was almost perfect. 
With that said, I used this and it seems to work fine, capturing special characters

`let range = tokenizer.rangeEnclosingPosition(end, with: .sentence, inDirection: .layout(.left))` and `let sentence = textView.text(in: range)` and `let currentWord = sentence.sentence.components(separatedBy: .whitespaces).last`

Answer (score 2):

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    NSString *string = [textView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:text];

    if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"] || [text isEqualToString:@" "])
    {
        NSString *currentString = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@" "];

        NSLog(@"currentWord==> %@",currentString);
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I already had this solution. The problem however is that you get the WHOLE string back AFTER a whitespace or linebreak character is detected. You don't get back the currently typed word, but the whole string in the `NSTextContainer`.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply extend `UITextView` and use following method which returns the word around the current location of cursor:

```
extension UITextView {

    func editedWord() -> String {

        let cursorPosition = selectedRange.location
        let separationCharacters = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: " ")

        // Count how many actual characters there are before the cursor.
        // Emojis/special characters can each increase selectedRange.location
        // by 2 instead of 1

        var unitCount = 0
        var characters = 0
        while unitCount < cursorPosition {

            let char = text.startIndex.advancedBy(characters)
            let int = text.rangeOfComposedCharacterSequenceAtIndex(char)
            unitCount = Int(String(int.endIndex))!
            characters += 1
        }


        let beginRange = Range(start: text.startIndex.advancedBy(0), end: text.startIndex.advancedBy(characters))
        let endRange = Range(start: text.startIndex.advancedBy(characters), end: text.startIndex.advancedBy(text.characters.count))

        let beginPhrase = text.substringWithRange(beginRange)
        let endPhrase = text.substringWithRange(endRange)

        let beginWords = beginPhrase.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(separationCharacters)
        let endWords = endPhrase.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(separationCharacters)

        return beginWords.last! + endWords.first!
    }
}
```

Comment: This crashes with emojis, how can that be fixed?

Comment: Nice solution. Covers cases when a user enters underscore/dots. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your `range` parameter from the `- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text` delegate method points at the exact place you change the `UITextView` string value.

The `location` property of the structure points to the changing string index, that's simple. The `length` not usually equals to `text.length`, be careful, user may select characters from the string to replace it with another string.