# How to pass value in uitextview using segue

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to create something in UITextView that every time the text encounter this kind of symbol "@". All text after that symbol will send to other controller.

here's my code

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)aTextView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {
    // "Length of existing text" - "Length of replaced text" + "Length of replacement text"
    NSInteger newTextLength = [self.addingText.text length] - range.length + [text length];

    if([text isEqualToString:@"@"] || secondString){
        secondString = true;

        NSString * stringToRange = [self.addingText.text substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0,range.location)];

        // Appending the currently typed charactor
        stringToRange = [stringToRange stringByAppendingString:text];

        // Processing the last typed word
        NSArray *wordArray       = [stringToRange componentsSeparatedByString:@"@"];
        self.getSecondString    = [wordArray lastObject];

        // wordTyped will give you the last typed object
        NSLog(@"\nWordTyped :  %@",self.getSecondString);

    }

    if (newTextLength > 50) {
        // don't allow change
         [aTextView resignFirstResponder];
        return NO;
    }
    self.countChar.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", (long)newTextLength];

    return YES;
}
```

I get that code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27379765/get-currently-typed-word-in-a-uitextview). It is perfectly work when I use NSLog but the time I click the button to send it to other controller using segue. It always show Null value. Hoping your help here. Thanks in advance

here's my button code

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

     CameraViewController * cameraViewController = (CameraViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];

    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"createText"]){

        NSLog(@"prepareForSegue: %@ == %@", self.addingText.text,self.getSecondString);
        cameraViewController.inputCreateText =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.addingText.text];
        cameraViewController.secondInputCreateText =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.getSecondString];
    }

}
```

Comment: show your button action method and show your designation view controller class for what you created the object

Comment: What is the output of your `NSLog`?

Comment: NSLog(@"prepareForSegue: %@ == %@", self.addingText.text,self.getSecondString); the value of self.getSecondString is still null. when the time I click button

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is you are modifying your string inside `textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:` which gets called for every typed in character. If your purpose is to send the string after `@` on tap on a button then do the calculation on button handler or inside `prepareForSegue:sender:`. If for some reason you want to stick to your own implementation then I would advise to put your targeted string inside `NSMutableArray` property created at class level so you don't loose data. And then you can combine all string inside that array like this `[arrayOfStrings componentsJoinedByString:@" "]`.

Comment: I will try your advice here