# Get word that is being typed

Tags: swift

I'm implementing a tagging feature similar to that of Facebook. So when I type @ and some character(s) after it, the function should return the word being typed.
So if the textView contains (and the cursor is at *c*)

**Hello @Jac !**

The function should return "@Jac"

If it contains (and the cursor is at *a*)

**Hello @Ja !**

Then the function should return "@Ja"

The final string of both examples would be,
**Hello Jack !**

I have attempted multiple solutions but none are working. One particular question was very similar to my question, but the solution has errors. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38969833/get-currently-typed-word-in-uitextview) is the link.

**Update 1**

Here is how I've set the delegate on the textView,

`postView.textView.delegate = self`

This is the code for detecting if the @ character was tapped (display the friends list table, if it was)

```
if let text = self?.characterBeforeCursor() {
    if (text == "@" && self?.friends.count != 0) {
        self?.friendTableView.isHidden = false
    } else {
        var word // Need to get the word being typed
        self?.displayedFriends = (self?.displayedFriends.filter { ($0["firstName"]?.hasPrefix(word))! })!
    }
}
```

**Update 2**

The solution below did not solve the problem. It is returning all text in the textfield instead of just the word that is being typed.

Comment: Why don't you use `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` ?

Comment: @AnuragSharma I'm having trouble with setting the range. Can you post a solution?

Comment: I don't see why this question got -1. Care to justify?

Comment: Checkout my solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/46828561/2020034

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a delegate function called `shouldChangeCharactersInRange`. From there you can get the current text after the user tapped the letter.

Make sure you use `UITextFieldDelegate` in your class declaration and set the textField's delegate to `self`.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    //get the updated text from the text field like this:
    let text = (textField.text as NSString?)?.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
    //note that we *need* to use the text as NSString, because the delegate method gives us an NSRange, rather than a Range which we can't use on String, but NSString, so we need to convert that first

    return true //so the text is visually updated in the textfield
}
```

---

#### Edit

I just saw that you posted about `UITextView`. It's pretty much the same:

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    let text = (textView.text as NSString?)?.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: text)

    return true
}
```

#### Edit 2

You need to also assign the text view's text to your variable in the code snippet you provided:

```
} else {
    var word = postView.textView.text
    self?.displayedFriends = (self?.displayedFriends.filter { ($0["firstName"]?.hasPrefix(word))! })!
}
```

Comment: How should I call this? The Facebook friends list being displayed in a UITableView.

Comment: Well you need to call this on the text field the user types in. So set the delegate of that text field.

Comment: Maybe I can help you better if you share some code.

Comment: Oh ok I get your problem. Why don't you just take the textView's text? `var word = postView.textView.text`

Comment: Ok. Testing it now... What should I put in the `string` variable in this line, `let text = (textView.text as NSString?)?.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145708/discussion-between-linusgeffarth-and-mjb).